# MPI hostfile under PBS

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, hpc, pbs

I am trying to run an MPI job on a cluster under PBS resource management. The cluster guide says I shouldn't have to worry about passing anything to `mpiexec`, as PBS should take care of that. For jobs on a single node, this is true and the job runs perfectly.

When I submit jobs requiring more than one node, the job exits saying it can't recognise the hosts. I included a routine in my PBS script to parse the `$PBS_NODEFILE`, and reconstruct a hosts file with the proper DNS suffix. PBS now recognises the hosts.

Now comes the troubling part: the hosts file I generate, isn't getting passed properly to `mpiexec`. See below for the hosts file I pass, and the output from the MPI process.

My hosts file:

```
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
cx1-25-3-1.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk
```

Output from the MPI process:

```
Host   : "cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk"
PID    : 32752
nProcs : 24
Slaves : 
23
(
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32753"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32754"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32755"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32756"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32757"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32758"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32759"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32760"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32761"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32762"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32763"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32764"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32765"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32766"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.32767"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.316"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.319"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.320"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.321"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.322"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.323"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.324"
"cx1-25-2-2.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk.325"
)
```

Should the list of processes be identical to the host file? Why doesn't `mpiexec` accept the host file?

The implementation is OpenMPI 1.6.0, and a MWE of my PBS script follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -l walltime=40:00:00
#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=12:mpiprocs=24:mem=4gb

module load openfoam/2.3.0 libscotch
pbsdsh2 cp -r $INPUT_DIR $TMPDIR/ 2>&1

# setting up hosts file
sed -n 1~24p $PBS_NODEFILE > hosts_buffer
for ii in `cat hosts_buffer`; do echo ${ii}.cx1.hpc.ic.ac.uk slots=12; done > hosts
nprocs=24;

# execution
mpiexec --hostfile hosts -np $nprocs $SOLVER 2>&1
```

Comment: Please include your pbs script as well

Comment: Which MPI implementation do you use and is it compiled with so-called _tight integration_ with PBS? Open MPI can be compiled with support for `tm` (the PBS API) and when so it can use the `tm` interface to both obtain information about the host list and to launch processes on remote nodes. To check if you MPI is Open MPI just issue: `mpicc --showme:version` and it should print the version of Open MPI.

Comment: MPI implementation is OpenMPI 1.6.0. - I didn't run `mpicc --showme:version` because it won't run if not in a PBS environment and the queues are very long, but I loaded the module and saw `$MPI_ARCH_PATH` and `$MPI_LIBS` pointing to the location for OpenMPI 1.6.0.

As for the compile flag, a quick `ompi_info | grep tm` showed
    MCA ras: tm (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6)
    MCA plm: tm (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6)
    MCA ess: tm (MCA v2.0, API v2.0, Component v1.6)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to skip 12 lines

```
sed -n 1~12p $PBS_NODEFILE > hosts_buffer
```

or

```
uniq $PBS_NODEFILE > hosts_buffer
```

And also I notice your host file has only 23 lines.

You could also try it this way:

```
cd  $PBS_O_WORKDIR
mpiexec -hostfile $PBS_NODEFILE  -np  `wc -l < $PBS_NODEFILE` $SOLVER 2>&1
```

Comment: I tried it the `uniq` way (which I agree is cleaner), and still ended up with all the slaves in my log corresponding to the same node, as shown in the OP.

The second way you suggested yields an error saying OpenFOAM cannot find the main control dictionary.

    `--> FOAM FATAL IO ERROR: 
    cannot find file
    file: /tmp/pbs.7477357.cx1b/system/controlDict at line 0.
    From function regIOobject::readStream()
    in file db/regIOobject/regIOobjectRead.C at line 73.
    FOAM exiting`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to your PBS directives.

Try changing from :

```
    #PBS -l select=2:ncpus=12:mpiprocs=24:mem=4gb
```

to :

```
    #PBS -l select=2:ncpus=12:mpiprocs=12:mem=4gb
```

This way, you request PBS to spawn 12 processes for each node instead of 24 processes previously.
I don't think you need to regenerate the host file.
Just run the code as :

```
    mpiexec -hostfile $PBS_NODEFILE -np 24 $SOLVER 2>&1
```

That should do it, hopefully.